# Alerts for blogs in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am creating a post for a blog in SharePoint 2013 and saving it as a draft. Is it possible to activate alerts for the saved as draft posts - before publishing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SharePoint allows the users to set alert for all type of list items. Hence, we can also enable to alert for draft items in Posts list under a blog site.

In the List ribbon select the "Set alert on this list" from Alert Me button.
[image: select the "Set alert on this list" from Alert Me button]

It opens a popup (Posts - New Alert), where we choose the options on when do we need the alert setup,
[image: Posts - New Alert page used to set the notifications]

I hope this can solve your requirement

Comment: I wanted to ask you another question. When I save a post as a draft and then edit it, my changes are shown on the alert but the text that was deleted and/or edited is also shown as stricken. How can I avoid the stricken text to be shown, I need to display just the final editing.